# JAXB Combine similar elements

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an XML source which produces XML in a format I cannot change.
The format is similar to:

```
    <entry name="bob" color="red"/>
    <entry name="bob" color="blue"/>
    <entry name="bob" color="green"/>
```

where the *name* attribute could be used for grouping.
The result after unmarshalling is something like

```
    class Entry {

        String name = "bob";
        String color = "red";

    }

    class Entry {

        String name = "bob";
        String color = "green";

    }
```

However I would like to combine these into something similar to:

```
    class Entry {

        String name = "bob";
        Set colors = { "red", "blue", "green" };

    }
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's easy to do this as part of the JAXB unmarshalling process. Also you should already have defined a `public Set<String> colors` as a field of the objects. It should be rather easy to implement as a separate second processing step:

```
entries = unmarshaller.unmarshal(...);
Map<String, Entry> compacted_entries = new HashMap<String, Entry>();
for (Entry entry: entries) {
   if compacted_entries.containsKey(entry.name)
     compacted_entries.get(entry.name).colors.add(entry.color);
   else
     compacted_entries.put(entry.name, entry);
     entry.colors = new HashSet<String>();
     entry.colors.add(entry.color);
   end
}
```